# Tortoise SVN cannot connect

Tags: svn, windows-10, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I am trying to load the URL using Tortoise SVN client. After the credential the interface doesn't show me the required repository. It is showing me the blank screen, picture is attached as reference.
I have **windows 10 64bit** and **Tortoise SVN v-1.11.1 x64**
Thanks in advance
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you enter an incorrect URL. The repository that you contact seems to be empty. Double-check that and contact an admin.

If it's not the case, try switching the server to HTTP(S) and use FQDN instead of IP name in the URL.